# "Your iCloud storage is almost full"

Tags: icloud, storage

The majority of my iCloud storage is in backups. 4.2GB in backups for my iPhone & iPad. Is this typical, 'cuz it seems like a lot to me?

Comment: You wonder if you backups can be 4.2GB?

Answer (score 1):

Why not thin out what you back up? If you manage iCloud (tap Settings, Tap your AppleID at the top, tap iCloud, it explains exactly what makes up the 4.2 GB of backups if you tap storage one more time.

In the Manage Storage - each backup can be thinned as needed or you can decide you want everything backed up and opt to pay for extra storage if needed.

Comment: all that I back up is contacts, calendar and notes. No photos.

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone, iPad backups are several Gigs each so your value of 4.2G seems reasonable. But iCloud is much more than that. I think it is initially 50G. If your iCloud Drive is almost full I'd check how much is being used by Photos and iTunes. You can also increase iCloud storage to 200 Gigs for $3 a month I think.

My backups are 1.6G fir iPhone and 1.4G for iPad. Photo library is 2.5G. My big memory hog is my documents folder. Its 44G. I accumulated a lot of stuff over the years.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Initially 5GB. 50GB is an upgrade option

Comment: No photos, No iTunes. Actually, iCloud offers 5G for free.